# ar_sendmail command not working with ruby 1.9.2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, sendmail, actionmailer, ar-mailer

I am not able to run `ar_sendmail` command from my terminal. I don't think i have missed its configuration. Below is my code;

```
development.rb
++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
ActionMailer::Base.delivery_method = :activerecord
ActionMailer::Base.smtp_settings = {
  :address => "smtp.gmail.com",
  :port => 25,
  :domain => "www.google.com",
  :authentication => :plain,
  :user_name => "ashis.lun@gmail.com",
  :password => "kathmandu",
  :enable_starttls_auto => true
}
require "action_mailer/ar_mailer"
```

```
Gemfile 
+++++++++++++++++++++++++++
gem "ar_mailer", "1.5.1"
```

```
My Mailer
++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
class Postoffice < ActionMailer::ARMailer
  def recover_password_email(account, name, address)
    @recipients = address
    @from = "ashis.lun@gmail.com"
    @subject = "Your Account at #{account.org_name} is Ready"
    @body["subdomain"] = account.subdomain
    @body["name"] = name
    @body["org_name"] = account.org_name
    @body["password"] = password
    @body["email"] = address
  end
end
```

```
My controller
++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
def reset_password
    @user = User.find_by_email(params[:email])

    begin
      if @user
        password = get_new_password
        @user.update_attributes!(:password => password)
        Postoffice.deliver_recover_password_email(@account, @user.individual.firstname, @user.email, password)
        flash[:notice] = "Your password has been e-mailed to you. It should show up in a minute!"
        redirect_to '/sessions/new'      
      end
    rescue
      flash[:notice] = "Sorry, there was a problem resetting your password."
      redirect_to '/sessions/new'
    end
  end
end
```

Whenever I run ar_sendmail command I just get below message. If i hit `RAILS_ROOT` in console then I it shows `/Users/me/Dev/a5his`

```
Usage: ar_sendmail [options]

ar_sendmail scans the email table for new messages and sends them to the
website's configured SMTP host.

ar_sendmail must be run from a Rails application's root or have it specified
with --chdir.

If ar_sendmail is started with --pid-file, it will fail to start if the PID
file already exists or the contents don't match it's PID.

Sendmail options:
    -b, --batch-size BATCH_SIZE      Maximum number of emails to send per delay
                                     Default: Deliver all available emails
        --delay DELAY                Delay between checks for new mail
                                     in the database
                                     Default: 60
        --max-age MAX_AGE            Maxmimum age for an email. After this
                                     it will be removed from the queue.
                                     Set to 0 to disable queue cleanup.
                                     Default: 604800 seconds
    -o, --once                       Only check for new mail and deliver once
                                     Default: false
    -p, --pid-file [PATH]            File to store the pid in.
                                     Defaults to /var/run/ar_sendmail.pid
                                     when no path is given
    -d, --daemonize                  Run as a daemon process
                                     Default: false
        --mailq                      Display a list of emails waiting to be sent

Setup Options:
        --create-migration           Prints a migration to add an Email table
                                     to stdout
        --create-model               Prints a model for an Email ActiveRecord
                                     object to stdout

Generic Options:
    -c, --chdir PATH                 Use PATH for the application path
                                     Default: .
    -e, --environment RAILS_ENV      Set the RAILS_ENV constant
                                     Default: 
    -t, --table-name TABLE_NAME      Name of table holding emails
                                     Used for both sendmail and
                                     migration creation
                                     Default: Email
    -v, --[no-]verbose               Be verbose
                                     Default: 
    -h, --help                       You're looking at it


ar_sendmail must be run from a Rails application's root to deliver email.

/Users/me/Dev/a5his does not appear to be a Rails application root.
```

Thanks in advance <><

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about using Delayed Job?  I've used ar mailer in the past and find delayed job a much better solution.

https://github.com/collectiveidea/delayed_job

Comment: Thanks Kevin and delayed job is great gem.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if it'll make a difference, but it says [here](http://seattlerb.rubyforge.org/ar_mailer/ActionMailer/ARMailer.html) to put

```
require "action_mailer/ar_mailer"
```

in `environment.rb`, not `development.rb` or `production.rb`. Other than that, I can't see anything you missed.

Comment: I think it doesn't matter if we put the above code in development.rb instead of environment.rb. Thank for the response.

Answer (score 0):

Try `ar_sendmail --chdir /Users/me/Dev/a5his` or changing into the root of your rails app before running the command

Comment: When i hit RAILS_ROOT in console, it shows /Users/me/Dev/a5his. Isn't this means i am in root of my app?

Answer (score 0):

ar_sendmail must be run from a Rails application's root to deliver email.
/Users/me/Dev/a5his does not appear to be a Rails application root.

Are you running the command in the application's root?

Comment: Yes, no doubt about that. a5his is my root folder.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
cd #{Rails.root.to_s} && bundle exec ar_sendmail_rails3 -e production
```

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the source (shown below), this message is displayed if loading config/environment fails. One instance of this I ran into was where a dependency was unmet, which was causing an exception to fire when config/environment was being loaded. To address this, you can use an irb session and try requiring config/environment to see what error may be causing the require to fail.

```
Dir.chdir options[:Chdir] do
  begin
    require 'config/environment'
  rescue LoadError
    usage opts, <<-EOF
  #{name} must be run from a Rails application's root to deliver email.
  #{Dir.pwd} does not appear to be a Rails application root.
      EOF
  end
end
```